# How to set up fields position?

Tags: html, css

Firefox, Safari, IE 
[image][image][image]

As you can see in different browsers appears 1-2 px difference between `input` and `div`, how to clear it?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="my-input-select" disabled="disabled"/>
<div class="my-input-select-box" >
    <ul style="z-index:100">
        <li>All</li>
        <li>Products</li>
        <li>Categories</li>
        <li>Clients</li>
        <li>News</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-input-select{
    border: 1px solid #acacac;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: url(images/forms/select.png) no-repeat 98% center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

div.my-input-select-box{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.my-input-select-box ul{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    left: 110px;
    top: 26px;
    width: 172px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.my-input-select-box li{
    border-bottom: medium none;
    color: #393939;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 2px 6px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide all the related code of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an html, css reset for example http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/